# How can I disable Vim's HTML error highlighting?

Tags: html, vim, syntax-highlighting

I use Vim to edit HTML with embedded macros, where the macros are bracketed with double angle brackets, e.g., "<>".  Vim's standard HTML highlighting sees the second "<" and ">" as errors, and highlights them as such.  How can I prevent this?  I'd be happy to either teach $VIMHOME/syntax/html.vim that double-angle-brackets are OK, or to simply disable the error highlighting, but I'm not sure how to do either one.  ("highlight clear htmlTagError" has no effect.  In fact, "highlight clear" has no effect in an HTML buffer.)

Comment: Yeah, that's the stopgap, but I'm hoping for better.  I've been reading up on syntax highlighting in Vim, but html.vim is a lot more complicated than the simple examples I've seen so far.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to introduce full syntax highlighting in your macros, it'll be easiest to start with a syntax file like `htmldjango` (`$VIMRUNTIME/syntax/htmldjango.vim`, which then uses `html.vim` and `django.vim` from the same directory); in it, there is special meaning in `{{ ... }}`, among other things. You want it just the same, but with `<<` and `>>` being your delimiters.

To just highlight `<< ... >>` specially, you'd need a syntax line like this:

```
syntax region mylangMacro start="<<" end=">>" containedin=ALLBUT,mylangMacro
```

And then you could highlight it with:

```
highlight default link mylangMacro Macro
```

This could either go in `~/.vim/after/syntax/html.vim` or could be done in the style of `htmldjango` as a new syntax highlighter (this would be my preferred approach; you can then make HTML files use this new syntax file with an autocmd).

---

(You can also remove the error highlighting with `syntax clear htmlTagError` which would go in the same sort of position. But hopefully you'll think getting separate highlighting is better than just removing the error.)

Comment: @user1408884: if that's what you need, remember to accept the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here are instructions to edit existing syntax highlighting in Vim:

http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/syntax.html#mysyntaxfile-add

vim runtime paths for Unix/Linux:

```
                   $HOME/.vim,
                    $VIM/vimfiles,
                    $VIMRUNTIME,
                    $VIM/vimfiles/after,
                    $HOME/.vim/after
```

> Create a directory in your vim runtime path called "after/syntax".

Commands for Unix/Linux:

```
mkdir ~/.vim/after
mkdir ~/.vim/after/syntax
```

> 1. Write a Vim script that contains the commands you want to use.  For    example, to change the colors for the C syntax:     **highlight cComment
>      ctermfg=Green guifg=Green**
> 2. Write that file in the "after/syntax" directory.  Use the name of the    syntax, with ".vim" added.  For our C syntax:     **:w
>      ~/.vim/after/syntax/c.vim**
>
> That's it.  The next time you edit a C file the Comment color will be
>   different.  You don't even have to restart Vim.
>
> If you have multiple files, you can use the filetype as the directory
>   name. All the "*.vim" files in this directory will be used, for
>   example:  ~/.vim/after/syntax/c/one.vim   ~/.vim/after/syntax/c/two.vim

Alternatively, you could take a much easier route and use syntax highlighting within the Nano command line editor, which you can define your own syntax very easily with regular expressions:

http://how-to.wikia.com/wiki/How_to_use_syntax_highlighting_with_the_GNU_nano_text_editor